# Store argv[] into two arrays divided by a special string (C)

Tags: c

I want to read the arguments from command line and store them into two arrays. The separation between the arrays will be denoted by "cut".

Example: a.out andy bob charlie ned cut amy sophie anna

array1 will be {andy, bob, charlie, ned}

array2 will be {amy, sophie, anna}

I found the argc of the word "cut". Then I ran a loop from 0 to that index for the first array. I am having trouble with the second array.

```
int cutindex, i;

for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
  if(strcmp("cut", argv[i]) == 0){
    cutindex = i;
  }
}

char argv1[10];
for(i=0; i<cutindex-1; i++) {
  argv1[i] = argv[i+1];
}

char argv2[10];
for(i=0; i<argc-cutindex-1; i++) {
  argv2[i] = argv[cutindex+1];
}
```

For the second array, I am getting a repetition of the first value (amy) for the entire array. What am I doing wrong?

Firstly, is there a better (more efficient) way to do this?

Comment: `argv[cutindex+1];` doesn't change in the second loop.

Comment: then use `char *argv1[10]`. array of _pointers_

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but if the program is invoked with `a.out amy cut bob cut charlie cut denise cut edward`, the split will occur at the `cut` before `edward`.   That is, the split is made at the last `cut`.  It also isn't entirely clear what result you want if the last argument is `cut`, nor whether intermediate `cut` arguments should be kept or not.

Comment: It would be tempting to replace the pointer to your chosen `cut` with a `NULL` pointer (`argv[cutindex] = NULL;`), and then `char **argv1 = &argv[1]; char **argv2 = &argv[cutindex + 1];`, giving you two null-pointer terminated lists.  That assumes you don't need the original argument list after this.  Or simply arrange to copy relevant subsections of the `argv` array into the new arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems that were pointed out in the comments:

1. In the third loop, the code uses `cutindex + 1` to index into the `argv` array. But the loop doesn't change `cutindex`, so the first argument after "cut" ("amy" in the example) is repeated for the entire array.
2. The output arrays `argv1` and `argv2` should be arrays of pointers.

One solution to the first problem is to use a separate index for each array. That way you can increment each index as needed, and don't need to attempt to compute indexes mathematically.

The added benefit is that when the code is finished, the final value of each output index is the count of elements in the corresponding output array.

Another added benefit is that you can limit the number of elements written to the array. Note that in the code below, any arguments after the first 10 are silently dropped. In real code, you might want to alert the user that they entered too many arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_ARG 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *argv1[MAX_ARG];   // first array of arguments
    int n1 = 0;             // index into first array

    char *argv2[MAX_ARG];   // second array of arguments
    int n2 = 0;             // index into second array

    // copy pointers into the first array until "cut" is found
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp("cut", argv[i]) == 0)
            break;
        if (n1 < MAX_ARG)
            argv1[n1++] = argv[i];
    }

    // copy any remaining pointers into the second array
    for (i++; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (n2 < MAX_ARG)
            argv2[n2++] = argv[i];
    }

    // print the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        printf("argv1[%d] = '%s'\n", i, argv1[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        printf("argv2[%d] = '%s'\n", i, argv2[i]);
}
```

When run with the command line

```
./a.out andy bob charlie ned cut amy sophie anna
```

the output of this code is

```
argv1[0] = 'andy'
argv1[1] = 'bob'
argv1[2] = 'charlie'
argv1[3] = 'ned'

argv2[0] = 'amy'
argv2[1] = 'sophie'
argv2[2] = 'anna'
```